# OpenAPI spec: default value of query param is ignored

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I've described a param within an OpenAPI 3 spec as

```yaml
review_requests:
  get:
    tags:
      - dashboard
    operationId: reviewRequests
    parameters:
      - name: page
        in: query
        default: 0
        description: Page number
        schema:
          type: integer
    responses:
      200:
        description: OK
```

After compilation I see that the default value is missing from Java code and the param is actually described like:

```java
@Valid @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page
```

and instead of `0` I receive `null` if the param is not supplied in GET request.
As far as I understand it should be

```java
@Valid @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution: in OpenAPI 3.x, the default value must be specified within the parameter's `schema`. In other words instead of

```yaml
    parameters:
      - name: page
        in: query
        default: 0
        description: Page number
        schema:
          type: integer
```

it should be

```yaml
    parameters:
      - name: page
        in: query
        description: Page number
        schema:
          type: integer
          default: 0
```